Why does QField crash when opening/editing a project from QFieldCloud?
I created a QField Project by converting the currently open QGIS Project to a QFieldCloud Project using the QFieldSync plug-in.
I then downloaded the QFieldCloud Project into QField on my mobile device. At first it opens with no issue. Then I try and test some of the layers' forms and QField crashes with no message log or error message. When I try to open the QField Project again, QField crashes as it opens.
Thinking maybe I did something wrong that I didn't notice before, I removed the QField Project locally (from the mobile device), then deleted the QFieldCloud Project from the cloud, then deleted the entire local mirror project files (from my computer), then redo the whole process from the beginning.
The problem still occurs; QField crashes when trying to open the project. No error message, no message log, just crash.
I am not doing anything different from the dozens of other QField projects I have created and used successfully (the same process as described above). This is a new mobile device (phone), but I have already used QField on it in different projects with no issue. The mobile device is a TCL 40XE5G running Android version 13.
What could be going on? How can I fix this?
This is the first time I have made a QFieldCloud Organization the owner when creating the QFieldCloud Project, could the problem be something to do with that?

Is there anything in the QGIS project logs? View-->Panels-->Log messages
